# Gnuplot use two different scales in the same axis

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to create a graphic using gnuplot 5.0 with two scales in the same x axis. I have managed to create one using the multiplot option with the following code:

```
reset

set terminal pngcairo
set output "test.png"

unset key
set ylabel "Temperature (C)"
set ytics nomirror
set yrange[0:7]

set multiplot layout 1,2

set xrange [0:5.99] #Avoid plotting the last xtics in the first graphic
set xlabel "Heating time (minutes)"
set rmargin at screen 0.7
plot x

set xrange [0:4]
set xlabel "Seconds after stop"
set rmargin
set lmargin at screen 0.7
set xtics 1
unset ylabel
unset ytics
set y2tics nomirror
set format y2 ''
f(x) = a * exp (-x*b)
a=6
b=1 
plot f(x)
```

With this result:

[image]

I want to generate several images like this one and add them in a multiplot arrangement, but I am not sure if using nested multiplots will be easy. Is there an easier way to obtain each of the images without using multiplot, like splitting the xaxis in two components?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to plot functions like `x` or `f(x)` as in your example or numerical data from a datafile? How does your input data look like? Please give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this still might be of interest to the OP or somebody else... You don't explicitly write whether you want to plot functions or data from a datafile. In your examples you use functions.

You can do something without "nested" multiplots, which would certainly  be possible as well, but probably getting a bit confusing.
So, maybe the following might be easier. You basically set the xtics "manually". In order to avoid typing the same code several times you can use macros (check `help macros`).

**Code:**

```
### multiplot graph with different x-axis scales
reset session

# define functions
Temperature(x) = x<t0 ? x*a/t0 : a*exp(-(x-t0)*b)
myColor(col) = column(col)<t0 ? 0xff0000 : 0x0000ff
myTic(x,t) = sprintf("%g", x<=t ? x : x-t)

# define macro
myPlot = "\
    set xrange[0:t0+t1]; \
    set arrow 1 from first t0, graph 0 to first t0, graph 1 nohead; \
    set label 1 'heating' center at first t0/2., graph 0 offset 0,-2; \
    set label 2 'cooling' center at first (t0+t1/2.), graph 0 offset 0,-2; \
    set xtics (); \
    do for [i=0:int(t0/dt1)] { set xtics add (myTic(i*dt1,t0) i*dt1) }; \
    do for [i=0:int(t1/dt2)] { set xtics add (myTic(i*dt2,t1) i*dt2+t0) }; \
    plot '+' u 1:(Temperature($1)):(myColor(1)) w l lc rgb var "

set samples 200
set key noautotitle
set bmargin 3
set ylabel "Temperature"
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 2,2

    t0=6; t1=4; dt1=1; dt2=1; a=6; b=1
    @myPlot

    t0=4; t1=10; dt1=1; dt2=2; a=4; b=0.5
    @myPlot

    t0=20; t1=30; dt1=5; dt2=10; a=2; b=0.1
    @myPlot

    t0=4; t1=4; dt1=1; dt2=1; a=10; b=1
    @myPlot

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. In my example I used functions for simplicity, but it could also be data read from a datafile. I thought that the code would be similar using functions or external data, but since you asked what kind of data was to be plotted, now I imagine that there are differences. Does the code change significantly in case I wanted to use a datafile?

Comment: @Emilio thanks your for feedback. After more than 3 years of no answer, you probably found another solution?!
If you plot functions, you give the range by `xrange[:]`. If you plot data, you have to get the range from the data, probably via `stats`.
And on top I noticed now, that you have minutes in the first part and seconds in the second part. For sure, this can also be handled, but hence, it will be important to know how your data is stored in your file(s). Will it be just one time column or two time columns for heating and cooling, etc.? Please edit your question and give data example.

Comment: @Emilio Is the question answered? Any response would be appreciated. Can you please give example data for your datafiles?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't find the data files I was using. If I remember correctly, for each plot I had one file for the heating time and a different file for the cooling time. In each file, the first column was the time and the second column was the temperature data. In any case, I think your answer is right for my question since I did not say anything about data being in files.